# Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation 5.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, nuget-package

I'm trying to install Nuget package **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation** on a .Net **core 3.1** project and getting following error.
"Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation 5.0.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1"

I have already updated all the existing packages but no luck.
Has anyone encountered this error?

Comment: `Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation 5.0.0` depends on `net5.0`.

Comment: Thanks Yinqui. I installed version 3.1.10 and it worked

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because `Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation 5.0.0` depends on `net5.0`.

You should install a version compatible with `.net core 3.1`,like `Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation -Version 3.x`

Comment: My question is, why is Visual Studio showing us this "update" in the first place (in the Updates section of the nuget manager)?

Comment: @BVernon because the NuGet Manager is very very "dumb". It always defaults to the highest version available no matter the dependencies/ compatiblilities

Comment: @Hobbamok That's fine that NuGet is dumb, but NuGet does have the meta information that Visual Studio could use to filter on. Hence my question, why aren't they filtering to proper results in Visual Studio? And I suppose the answer is likely that they just haven't gotten enough complaints about it.

Answer (score 4):

For me this one worked in the integrated VS terminal.

`dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation --version 3.1.10`

Answer (score 0):

Installed version 3.1.10 and resolved.

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation -Version 3.1.10
```

Comment: Even when I install this version, Visual Studio still suggests I can update to the version mentioned above which obviously won't work.

Comment: Yes. They already released the version 5.0.0. which is compatible for .NET 5.0 and VS doesnt compare the .NET version of the project. I feel bit misleading